# Can could someone please explain to me why these errors are coming up when I compile this code?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

```
class GradeCalculator
{
//instance variables
String name;
double q1;
double q2;
double q3;
double q4;
double q5;
double midterm;
double finalExam;
double finalGrade;

//constructor
GradeCalculator (String studentName, double quizOne, double quizTwo, double quizThree, double quizFour, double quizFive, double midterm, double finalExam)
{
name = studentName;
q1 = quizOne;
q2 = quizTwo;
q3 = quizThree;
q4 = quizFour;
q5 = quizFive;
}

//method
public double calculator (double q1, double q2, double q3, double q4, double q5, double midterm, double finalExam)
{
finalGrade = ((((q1 + q2 + q3 + q4 + q5) / 50) * 100) / 2 ) + (midterm / 4 ) + (finalExam / 4);
return finalGrade;

if (90 <= finalGrade && finalGrade <= 100)
```

Right here is the first error. Java says that this is an unreachable statement and I have no clue what that means or how to fix it.

```
{
System.out.println (name + "'s final grade is " + finalGrade + " and " + name + "'s letter grade is A.");
}
else
{
if (80 <= finalGrade && finalGrade <= 89)
{
System.out.println (name + "'s final grade is " + finalGrade + " and " + name + "'s letter grade is B.");
}
else
{
if (70 <= finalGrade && finalGrade <= 79)
{
System.out.println (name + "'s final grade is " + finalGrade + " and " + name + "'s letter grade is C.");
}
else
{
if (60 <= finalGrade && finalGrade <= 69)
{
System.out.println (name + "'s final grade is " + finalGrade + " and " + name + "'s letter grade is D.");
}
else
{
if (finalGrade <= 59)
{
System.out.println (name + "'s final grade is " + finalGrade + " and " + name + "'s letter grade is F.");
}
}
}
}
}
}
}

public class GradeCalculatorTester
{
public static void main (String[]args)
{
GradeCalculator student1 = new GradeCalculator ("Eddie Cardona", 8, 7, 9, 10, 8, 87, 92);
GradeCalculator student2 = new GradeCalculator ("Aleksandr Marchant", 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 63, 72);
GradeCalculator student3 = new GradeCalculator ("James Wilson", 7, 8, 8, 7, 5, 75, 80);
GradeCalculator student4 = new GradeCalculator ("Jordan Matthewson", 10, 9, 10, 8.5, 9, 94, 96);
GradeCalculator student5 = new GradeCalculator ("Seamus O'Dorherty", 5, 6, 9, 7, 7, 74, 80);

student1.calculator(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam);
student1.calculator(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam);
student1.calculator(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam);
student1.calculator(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam);
student1.calculator(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam);
```

The rest of the errors happen in the section above when the objects call the method.
    }
    }
I have no idea why this won't work. When I compile this I end up with 37 errors. Help please! I am using a Java pack (j2sdk1.4.2_19) to do this.

Comment: Any statement after a `return` is unreachable.

Comment: It's illegal because it's **AFTER** a `return` statement, and will never be reached/executed.

Comment: You need a closing braces after your method call. Basically that's the syntax and nothing can lie outside of those braces.

Comment: I hope your actual code is indented.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly okay to put if/else statements within a method in Java, however, because it is after your return statement, it will be unreachable.

Also, not pertaining to your question, but a simpler and more aesthetically pleasing way to call all of those `double` variables would be to just say:

```
double q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, midterm, finalExam, finalGrade;
```

rather than having it spelled out in  separate lines.